# eval giving syntax error even when correct code given

Tags: python, eval

I have the following code, which uses the `eval` function:

```
lines = self.fulltext.splitlines()

CURRENT = 0

extractors = { "solar zenith angle" : (CURRENT, 1, "self.solar_z"),
                       "ground pressure" : (CURRENT, 2, "self.ground_pressure")                     

             }

print locals()

for line in lines:
    for label, details in extractors.iteritems():
        if label in line:
            if details[0] == CURRENT:
                values = line.split()
                eval("%s = values[%d]" % (details[2], details[1]))
```

However, when I run it I get the following error:

```
eval("%s = values[%d]" % (details[2], details[1]))
  File "<string>", line 1
    self.solar_z = values[1]
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is this? `self.solar_z` is defined, and the statement that is eval'd looks correct.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Use a `dict` if you need to store values by strings, don't dynamically create variables. It's at least as simple, doesn't screw with *your* scope, doesn't have to associated potential security risks, is much harder to break (no way it could possibly generate a syntax error, for instance) performs better, etc. - it's simply better, and by a large magin at that. (And this has nothing to do with functional programming.)

Comment: @delnan: The reason that I'm using variables like this is that I want to allow the users of the class to access the variables as class.variable, rather than having to do class.dict['variablename'].

Comment: You can do that by adding a `__getattr__` method to the class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [exec](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/exec.html) instead, it does evaluate statements, to.

`exec "self.solar_z = values[1]" in locals(), locals()`

Answer (score 7):

`eval()` evaluates expressions. Assignment in Python is a statement. This will not work.